# How to view hidden formatting elements (such as new-line, or tab) within any file, say plain text, in Unix command line?

Tags: file, unix, textview, formatting, text-editor

Is there a way to visualise hidden formatting elements in a file while using UNIX terminal (I use bash)? What I am looking for is  shown as say /s OR  shown as /t.

**The reason I am looking for this is sometime when I have created or edited a list in a plaintext file in Windows by copy pasting cells from an .xlsx, `sort -u` stops working on the file.** Then I have to run the following to make it work again:

```
tr -d '\15\32' < filename
```

It would be very helpful if we could see these things and other things as well such as internal file separators for more efficient use of `awk -F`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hexdump for this

```
hexdump -c file
```

which will return something like

```
0000000   s   p   a   c   e       a   t       e   n   d       o   f    
0000010   l   i   n   e      \n   t   a   b       a   t       e   n   d
0000020       o   f       l   i   n   e  \t  \n  \n                    
000002b
```

Comment: This works wonderfully to see spaces, \t and \n. However, this does not help me with my specific problem i.e. "something" is added when copy - pasting cells into a plain text  list which breaks "sort -u". Doing tr -d '\15\32' helps, but I still want to visualise these problematic elements.

Comment: \15\32 is a carriage return, or "\r", which is usually added at the end of lines in windows files. A fix is to use `dos2unix filename` or `sed -i 's/\r//g' filename` but I don't know if there's any way for you to disable the source files containing \r in the first place as they come from windows

Comment: yea, this is great and your suggestion does work, but is there a way you know of, I can visualise these things?

Comment: @ChiranjeevDas96 - The given command _can visualise these things_ as well; it displays \15 as `\r` and \32 as `032`.

Comment: @Armali oh it can? The file i tried it on showed my all \n \t and white spaces but not \r or 032. Interesting.